# SE Android app cannot show the full site name in title

Tags: feature-request, android-app

[image]

When browsing a specific stack in the Android app, there doesn't seem to be a way to see the whole site name, only the first 8 characters or so. Usually that's not a problem, but when you're active in Metas, suddenly there's little to differentiate between Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow, and maybe others too.

A minor issue, but a UX annoyance regardless.

One possible change would be to expand the site name field when it's touched and the menu is displayed. It can expand to cover the toolbar to the right.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a limitation of long site name on a given small space. Currently, the only workaround (which is not so practical) is to rotate the device to landscape to give more space to the title...

Comment: I can think of other options. Maybe expand the name box when clicked.